# How to specify preprocessor options in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

On Linux with g++ I use `-DPROGRAMNAME_VERSION=1.6` and `-DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG` to properly set some text and increase the speed of execution respectively.  I am doing some testing on Windows and am having trouble duplicating the executable with VS 2013. I searched around SO and found suggestions for Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions.  This agrees with Microsoft's documentation found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx.  The problem is that when I try to do it with

```
/DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG
/DPROGRAMNAME_VERSION=1.6
```

The log file shows the default value of version 1.00 and the execution time is twice that of the expected time.
The `/DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG` is used for C++ Eigen while the other is used as such:

```
#ifndef PROGRAMNAME_VERSION
#define PROGRAMNAME_VERSION 1.00
#endif
```

Both have been tested and work on Linux.  The answers on SO have been accepted which makes me think there is some small trick I am missing to make this work.

Comment: I'm guessing you put `/DPROGRAMNAME_VERSION=1.6` into the settings instead of `PROGRAMNAME_VERSION=1.6`. MS build will insert the `/D` for you when invoking the compiler.

Comment: Versions of `cl` since about 1990 has accepted `-` as well as `/`. But I think the question is about using the IDE to set these things - which is definitely possible, but I'm at least 6 years out of date, so can't say for sure what the current IDE options are - something like "Preprocessor Options", I expect.

Comment: @Praetorian you were correct I was including the /D in there.  I tried it with the / and with - and with just a leading D.  I never figured I needed to remove the D entirely.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Praetorian gave the correct answer.  Visual Studio doesn't use the same /D or -D that g++, etc use.  It inserts that for you.  The correct usage is as shown in his comment.

> I'm guessing you put /DPROGRAMNAME_VERSION=1.6 into the settings instead of PROGRAMNAME_VERSION=1.6. MS build will insert the /D for you when invoking the compiler. – Praetorian